# How do I import pygame on 3.7.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm running python 3.7.1 on my MacBook and it has been running perfectly until I tried importing pygame. I'm taking an intro to python class and we always just do `from module import *`. When I tried to do that same format with `pygame` I just got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`

What should I do about using `pygame` or should I just forget using `pygame` altogether

I'm new to python and the reason I'm trying to use `pygame` is that I'm making a game where the user controls a **.gif** or a spaceship and tries to avoid asteroids. All of my code is solid accept for the collision detection. Everyone seems to point me towards using `pygame` but i can't get that to work. Should I continue to use `pygame` and if so, how do i fix my problem? Should I drop pygame altogether and just try collision detection a different way; (if so, what other way?)

Comment: Does Pygame come standard with Python? You may need to install it.

Answer (score 3):

pygame is not bundled in standard python.

to install pygame in Mac, see 
[Mac installation from pygame.org](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Mac%20installation)

Also, `from module import *` is not a good practice if you're using more modules,

which will causes class name conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it - forget 3.7.1 go on the [Python](http://Python.org) website (linked) and download 3.6.7 ther when your setting up click add to PATH then you need to install pygame ( save it locally near where python is saved) then go on to terminal by going to finder and clicking applications and search terminal and type `pip install pygame` if there is anything you are confused about just ask (:
[Path button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsERo.png)

Comment: Why avoid python 3.7 in favor of python 3.6? What's the benefit?